# arcgis server 10, .net web api samples

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, vb.net

i am running arcgis server 10, installed visual web developer express 2010 edition, now wanted to run samples from arcgis.com for .net web api, for example the following one

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ADF_Tutorials/000200000025000000/

I downloaded the vb.net zipped folder shown for all files on above link. Unzipped it. Opened the "ADFTutorials_VBNet2010.sln" file. The visual web developer 2010 express says that

```
 One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.
 Please see the Output Window for details.
```

The output shows the following

```
 http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/ScriptableControls/MapCoordinateDisplayWebSite :  
 error  : Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet
 /ScriptableControls/MapCoordinateDisplayWebSite'.  The Web site 'http://localhost
 /ADFTutorials_VBNet/ScriptableControls/MapCoordinateDisplayWebSite' does not exist.


 http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/AccessArcGISServer : error  : Unable to open the 
 Web site 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/AccessArcGISServer'.  The Web site 
'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/AccessArcGISServer' does not exist.


 http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/AccessArcIMS : error  : Unable to open the Web 
 site 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/AccessArcIMS'.  The Web site 
 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/AccessArcIMS' does not exist.

 http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/ADFWebControls : error  : Unable to open the Web 
 site 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/ADFWebControls'.  The Web site 
 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/ADFWebControls' does not exist.


  http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/UsingCommonAPI : error  : Unable to open the 
  Web site 'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/UsingCommonAPI'.  The Web site   
  'http://localhost/ADFTutorials_VBNet/UsingCommonAPI' does not exist.
```

Please can anyone explain how to run the samples provided for .net? thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Website is not operative, have you set your IIS server up?

Comment: If you are just getting started with ArcGIS Server development, I would _highly_ recommend to use one of the Web APIs (JS, Flex, Silverlight) instead of the Web ADF. The Web ADF has been deprecated and the Web APIs provide a much better framework for creating good looking and scalable web apps. If you're a .NET developer then the Esri Silverlight API is an obvious place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You need a virtual directory in IIS to point to the location you unzipped your package.
[image: IIS image]

Comment: thanks, does it have to point to ...adftutorials\VBNet\ADFTutorials_VBNet or to ...adftutorials\VBNet\ADFTutorials_VBNet\AccessArcGISServer? and what should i do after this? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I created a Virtual Directory and named it test098, and pointed folder location to ...adftutorials\VBNet\ADFTutorials_VBNet\AccessArcGISServer, then in properties created Application name, and set the execute permissions to 'Scripts only', selected 'ArcGISApplicationsAppPool' for application pool. Then opened web browser and put url http://arcgis-server/test098/default.aspx it says "Server Application Unavailable". Plz can you show everything step by step? thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: so the samples can run "asis" you should create the vd as "adftutorials". You should only need the one vd. then when you open the ADFTutorials_VBNet2010.sln all the links will resolve.